# Apache rewrite rule based on a host

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2, apache2.4

I have the following configuration, basically its a reverse proxy in front of grafana. I forward the /logout request to the auth server with redirect url and the /login url to /login/generic_oauth.

I want to redirect the /logout to auth server only when the request is from grafana itself that is only if the grafana ui makes the request.

If the request is made by any other origin it should go to the reverse proxy and back. Basically when I logout the user from my angular app I to logout the user my grafana app too. But as I have chained the /logout to the auth server redirect I get a cors error when I make the request.

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^/logout - [C]

  I want to excute this rule only if the request is from http://grafana-ip:3001
  RewriteRule . "https://auth-server-ip:31443/auth/realms/MDC/protocol/openid-connect/logout?redirect_uri=http://auth-server-ip:8081/login" [NE,R=302,CO=grafana_sess:INVALID:;]

  RewriteRule ^/login$ /login/generic_oauth [L,R=302]

  ProxyPass / http://grafana-ip:3001/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://grafana-ip:3001/
  RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"

  Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
  Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
  Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "*"
```

Is there any way I can execute the rule as it is when request is from grafana-ip but not when it is form any other origin

Answer (score 0):

Since you proxy / to the backend, and your clients only request URL's on your proxy w/ referers referencing your proxy, you really have no reason to make the /logout handling conditional. Which is good because you have no ability to discriminate on anything for the same reasons.